# Pandas - Extracting data from Series

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to extract a seat of data from a column that is of type `pandas.core.series.Series`.

I tried

```
df['col1'] = df['details'].astype(str).str.findall(r'name\=(.*?),')
```

but the above returns null

Given below is how the data looks like in column `df['details']`

```
[{'id': 101, 'name': 'Name1', 'state': 'active', 'boardId': 101, 'goal': '', 'startDate': '2019-01-01T12:16:20.296Z', 'endDate': '2019-02-01T11:16:00.000Z'}]
```

Trying to extract value corresponding to `name` field

**Expected output** : `Name1`

Comment: where is 'details' defined ? you are reading 'details' field from DataFrame but can not see that field in the data sample given by you ?

Comment: @ShankarSaranSingh, sorry forgot to mention.. df['details'] is the field from which I am trying to extract this data. Sample data I have added is from this field..

Comment: Do you have `dict`s in your columns? This is usually not what you're supposed to do in Pandas. Why don't you split the fields out into individual columns?

Comment: @scottmartin check the given solution if sounds good do accept as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: simple, change according to your need.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 101, 'name': 'Name1', 'state': 'active', 'boardId': 101, 'goal': '', 'startDate': '2019-01-01T12:16:20.296Z', 'endDate': '2019-02-01T11:16:00.000Z'}])
print(df['name'][0])
```

#or if DataFrame inside a column itself

```
df['details'][0]['name']
```

NOTE: as you mentioned details is one of the dataset that you have in the existing dataset

Comment: `df['details']` is a column in my existing DataFrame so I am trying to extract data from one of the fields in the existing Dataframe.

Comment: if you can share the exact data with some random values that will be better to answer, df['details'] will fetch details column similarly df['name'] is fetching name column just the name is different, however if something we are missing you should add in question, I will look back.

Comment: Welcome, happy coding :)

Comment: how could I extend this same to be applied to every row of the DataFrame.

Comment: It depends what you want to do further, clear business requirements can ease out better implementation, if just want to know how to do for other rows it's same just change the index from 0 to current index.

Comment: I am trying to add in a new column to the existing DataFrame that would just extract the  `name ` value from the  `df['details'] ` field and populate it in this newly created column in the same DataFrame but I am trying to perform this to every row in the Dataframe

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 101, 'name': 'Name1', 'state': 'active', 'boardId': 101, 'goal': '', 'startDate': '2019-01-01T12:16:20.296Z', 'endDate': '2019-02-01T11:16:00.000Z'}])

#Name column
print(df.name)

#Find specific values in Series

indeces = df.name.str.find("Name") #Returns indeces of such values

df.iloc[index] # Returns all columns that fields name contain "Name"

df.name.iloc[index] # Returns all values from column name, which contain "Name"
```

Hope, this example will help you.

**EDIT:**
Your data frame has column 'details', which contain a dict {'id':101, ...}

```
>>> df['details']
0    {'id': 101, 'name': 'Name1', 'state': 'active'...
```

And you want to get value from field 'name', so just try:

```
>>> df['details'][0]['name']
'Name1'
```

Comment: df['details'] is a column in my existing DataFrame so I am trying to extract data from one of the fields in the existing Dataframe

Answer (score 1):

The structure in your series is a dictionary.

```
[{'id': 101, 'name': 'Name1', 'state': 'active', 'boardId': 101, 'goal': '', 'startDate': '2019-01-01T12:16:20.296Z', 'endDate': '2019-02-01T11:16:00.000Z'}]
```

You can just point to the element 'name' from that dict with the following command

```
df['details'][0]['name']
```

If the name could be different you can get the list of the keys in the dictionary and apply your regex on that list to get your field's name.

Hope that it can help you.

Comment: what if I had to run this through a list of 1000 rows how could I modify the index col in the above code you suggested.. Change id from 0 through every row of the DataFrame `df['details'][0]['name']`